# phalcon valida campos para que no se repitan?

Tags: php, mysql, phalcon

Bueno días.

Mi duda es sobre si phalcon hace por defecto la validación de un campo para que no se duplique al crear un usuarario, especificamente para que no deje duplicar el número de identificación.

Muchas gracias por su ayuda, quedo atenta a sus respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

Encontre sobre **unique** en los campos del modelo, te paso la liga de la documentación espero y te sirva:

https://olddocs.phalconphp.com/en/3.0.0/reference/model-validation.html

Comment: Hola jdaramburoc, sería conveniente que añadieses las partes claves de la página enlazada en la propia repuesta (porque los enlaces se rompen o dejan de funcionar y entonces tu respuesta dejaría de tener sentido). Lee [answer] para más información.